# Spotify does not have icon on systray in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, icons, ubuntu-14.04, spotify

Today the Spotify was updated and its icon disappear on systray on ubuntu 14.04. I used to use this icon to play and stop the musics.

I modified the spotify.desktop and put some entries to control the music using the own spotify icon.

To edit the spotify.desktop, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop
```

And replace its content by this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spotify
GenericName=Music Player
Comment=Spotify streaming music client
Icon=spotify-client
Exec=spotify %U
TryExec=spotify
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Audio;Music;Player;AudioVideo;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/spotify
Actions=PlayOrPause;Stop;Next;Previous
​
[Desktop Action PlayOrPause]
Name=Play or Pause
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
​
[Desktop Action Stop]
Name=Stop
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Stop
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
​
[Desktop Action Next]
Name=Next
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
​
[Desktop Action Previous]
Name=Previous
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Now, you can controll the spotify using

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2lza.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to askubuntu

Comment: Do you know of something to make the "Offline mode" checkbox/option appear again? Even in that menu? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use this workaround but after the modification I can not start Spotify..